# Why does moving the start of the comment down one line of whitespace break compilation of this JavaScript code in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, syntax

I'm having to use WordPress for this particular page, and I wouldn't put it past WordPress to have a bug here, but maybe it is just the JavaScript.  Why does this compile:

```
    var pData = jQuery.parseJSON(pData);
    var strInnerHTML = "";
    /*
    for (var i = 0; true; i++) {
        var obj = pData[i.toString()];
        if (obj) {
            strInnerHTML += '<option value="' + obj.key + '">' + obj.value + '</option>\n';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    alert(strInnerHTML.slice(0, strInnerHTML.length - 2));
    document.getElementById("selectNations").innerHTML = strInnerHTML.slice(0, strInnerHTML.length - 2);*/
```

and yet this doesn't:

```
    var pData = jQuery.parseJSON(pData);
    var strInnerHTML = "";

    /*for (var i = 0; true; i++) {
        var obj = pData[i.toString()];
        if (obj) {
            strInnerHTML += '<option value="' + obj.key + '">' + obj.value + '</option>\n';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    alert(strInnerHTML.slice(0, strInnerHTML.length - 2));
    document.getElementById("selectNations").innerHTML = strInnerHTML.slice(0, strInnerHTML.length - 2);*/
```

**EDIT**

This is the first example in its full form.  In the first example, I'm able to see `alert("spam");` getting executed when I load the page, but not in the second example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // A text file had to be used, since WordPress wouldn't let me upload a JSON file.
alert("spam");
    jQuery.get("someJSONFileInTheFormOfATextFile", function(pData) {
        var pData = jQuery.parseJSON(pData);
        var strInnerHTML = "";
/*
        for (var i = 0; true; i++) {
            var obj = pData[i.toString()];
            if (obj) {
                strInnerHTML += '<option value="' + obj.key + '">' + obj.value + '</option>\n';
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        alert(strInnerHTML.slice(0, strInnerHTML.length - 2));
        document.getElementById("selectNations").innerHTML = strInnerHTML.slice(0, strInnerHTML.length - 2);*/
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "compile". Do you mean that the second piece of code doesn't execute? Are you generating JS with PHP?

Comment: Is WP doing anything to the JS here? (uglyfying etc). Both code examples above execute fine in console. What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: It's just that it's not running in the second example, but WordPress isn't showing compilation errors.

Comment: What do you mean by compilation errors? I still don't understand. Why would Wordpress throw any errors on your JavaScript? If you're mixing JS with PHP is probable that you have a syntax error somewhere. If the page just fails to load, check your server logs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what happened.  When I first started playing with WordPress the other night, I noticed that its Text/HTML tag on a page's editing screen tries to find newline characters in your code and add its own code around them behind your back.  They think this is "convenient and simple".  Well, this principle apparently extends to JavaScript inside of `script` tags.  If you do this in JavaScript:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
```

then WordPress will try to insert extra characters on and around that blank line on the finished page without telling you.  This will break your JavaScript code.  One way to work around it though is to just insert `//` everywhere you plan for a line to be blank:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
//
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
```

This will get WordPress to more-or-less stay out of your way.  In the second example in the question, there was a blank line  which was not existent in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `autop` in the post editor for all posts/pages so WP doesn't add paragraph breaks.

Use these filters in your theme's functins.php file to disable for `the_content` or `the_excerpt`, or use both:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

*From http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop*

**Or, do the following, which leaves `autop` enabled globally, but lets you disable it with `<!-- noformat on -->` and `<!-- noformat off -->` tags in individual posts and pages.**

After you add the function below to your theme's `functions.php` file, use can use the two tags

`<!-- noformat on -->` and `<!-- noformat off -->`

in your page/post editor, i.e.

```
    text will be rendered *with* autop

    <!-- noformat on -->

    text will be rendered *without* autop

    <!-- noformat off -->

    text will be rendered *with* autop
```

Content outside of the two format tags will have autop enabled, as noted.

Add to functions.php of your theme:

```
// <!-- noformat on --> and <!-- noformat off --> functions

function newautop($text)
{
    $newtext = "";
    $pos = 0;

    $tags = array('<!-- noformat on -->', '<!-- noformat off -->');
    $status = 0;

    while (!(($newpos = strpos($text, $tags[$status], $pos)) === FALSE))
    {
        $sub = substr($text, $pos, $newpos-$pos);

        if ($status)
            $newtext .= $sub;
        else
            $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

        $pos = $newpos+strlen($tags[$status]);

        $status = $status?0:1;
    }

    $sub = substr($text, $pos, strlen($text)-$pos);

    if ($status)
        $newtext .= $sub;
    else
        $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

    //To remove the tags
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[0], "", $newtext);
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[1], "", $newtext);

    return $newtext;
}

function newtexturize($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

function new_convert_chars($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'newautop');

remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
add_filter('the_content', 'newtexturize');

remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
add_filter('the_content', 'new_convert_chars');
```

Comment: Thanks!  That page says to add two function calls to `functions.php` to turn `wpautop` completely off, but it doesn't say where.  Where do you add them in that file?

Comment: That page indicates where to add the two functions: to your theme's functions.php file

Comment: I added them there, but I wasn't sure where in that file they needed to go.  When I did that, it took down WordPress.  The file itself is pretty long, and it's their 2014 theme.